# carrierwave rails 5 don't store the whole path of image file

Tags: save, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave, pathname

Carrierwave Rails 5 only store the image filename not the whole pathname.

## in models/profile.rb

```
mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
```

It stores the image file in the right uploads folder, so my AvatarUploader is working correctly.
But the :avatar attribute has only filename not the whole pathname.

## profile.avatar =>

```
"thumb_8eb67953-d383-4c1f-a42d-662903386814.jpg"
```

Do I need to do something `before_save` or `after_save` in `models/profile.rb` with :avatar attribute to point to the right location?

```
../app/assets/images/uploads/profile/avatar/20/thumb_8eb67953-d383-4c1f-a42d-662903386814.jpg
```

Thank you for helping,

Answer (score 1):

you can use 
`profile.avatar.url`

It will give whole path of file. for more reference read [This.](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#user-content-changing-the-storage-directory)

Comment: Thank you,<%= image_tag @profile.avatar.url(:thumb) %>  = >"/app/assets/images/uploads/profile/avatar/20/e3ec13bc-f5c3-4703-89d8-65f2f35ba42a.jpg" now I got this error ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/app/assets/images/uploads/profile/avatar/20/thumb_e3

Comment: and Please accept my answer if it's solve your issue.